# Showing $\Bbb Z_2 + \Bbb Z_3$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_6$.

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism, direct-product

> I want to show that $\Bbb Z_2 +\Bbb Z_3$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_6$ where '$+$' stands for external direct product.

First of all I wrote all the six elements of $\Bbb Z_2 + \Bbb Z_3$ and found the orders of each element. I observe that $\Bbb Z_2 +\Bbb Z_3$ and $\Bbb Z_6$ have same number of elements with number of elements of same order equal. What mapping should I define here in a valid way to show isomorphism?

I already know a theorem that when $\gcd(m,n)=1$, $\Bbb Z_m +\Bbb Z_n$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_{mn}$. Shall I mention this theorem and let it go? Or other way is possible to show this?

Comment: Perhaps you need to construct an isomorphism explicitly. Find a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: If you've got a theorem that does the work for you, then by all means use it. It's certainly true that $\gcd(2,3)=1$. Otherwise, you'd want to show an explicit isomorphism.

Comment: Ok that means the other way is to show that $Z_2 + Z_3$ is cyclic. Thanks

Comment: @Kavita, you can also find out that the order of product in abelian group is the least common multiple of orders of the elements, thus, you can take $(1,1)$, or  $(1,2)$ for generator

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

**Hint 2:** Consider the element $([1]_2, [1]_3)$.